# How can I redirect to the previous page after login in the Ultimate Membership Pro plugin on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I have been stuck on this assignment for work for a while (We don't have an IT-department and my experience with wordpress is pretty much non-existent). We use the Ultimate Membership pro plugin to handle our redirects (for example redirects after login and logout), and the problem is, whenever someone clicks on a restricted link without being logged in, they're asked to log in and after successfully doing that, they're redirected to the homepage of the website, and not to the previous page that they originally wanted to go to.

I have been unable to find an option within the plugin to get over this problem and I have also installed another plugin (Sky Login Redirect) to try to work around the problem but did not succeed.